# Apache - CSS does not link to my web page

Tags: css, bash, apache

I configured a web server so when I access to my localhost, a `bash` script runs and echoes an HTML document so the browser can render it. This works correctly.

I'm having troubles making the CSS work. It keeps throwing `GET http://172.20.10.6/css/styles.css net::ERR_ABORTED 500 (Internal Server Error)` in the console when accessing the web page.

I have a folder named `webserver` (`/var/www/webserver`) and inside the folder I have an `index.sh` that provides the HTML successfully and a folder `css` with the `styles.css` file.

This is the `.conf` file for my virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin user@localhost
    ServerName Test
    ServerAlias Test
    DocumentRoot /var/www/webserver

    ScriptAlias "/" "/var/www/webserver/"
    <Directory "/var/www/webserver">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/var/www/webserver/css">
        <Files *.css>
            Header set Content-type "text/css"
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    <IfModule dir_module>
        DirectoryIndex index.sh
    </IfModule>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And this is how I link my CSS file in the HTML:

```
echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"css/styles.css\">"
```

But then the 500 error comes, what can I do?

**EDIT**

This is the error logs I get when accessing the web page:

```
AH01215: (13)Permission denied: exec of '/var/www/webserver/css/styles.css' failed: /var/www/webserver/css/styles.css, referer: http://172.20.10.6/
End of script output before headers: styles.css, referer: http://172.20.10.6/
```

So I thought it was all about permissions and executed `chmod 777 css/styles.css` and restarted the server.

Now the error I get through console is: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)` and in `error.log` file:

```
AH01215: (8)Exec format error: exec of '/var/www/webserver/css/styles.css' failed: /var/www/webserver/css/styles.css, referer: http://172.20.10.6/
End of script output before headers: styles.css, referer: http://172.20.10.6/
```

I have also tried to add `AddType text/css .css` line in an `.htaccess` file or in the `.conf` file of the web server without any success. Also, I have `mime.load` and `headers.load` mods enabled in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled`.

Full `index.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "Content-type: text/html\n\n"

echo "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=\"en\" dir=\"ltr\">
  <head>
    <meta charset=\"utf-8\">
    <title>Server Manager</title>

    <link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"css/styles.css\">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>

    </header>

    <nav class=\"menu\">
      <ul>
        <li class=\"menu-item\">
          <span></span>
          <div class=\"menu-item-text\">Manage tasks</div>
        </li>
        <li class=\"menu-item selected\">
          <span></span>
          <div class=\"menu-item-text\">Monitoring</div>
        </li>
        <li class=\"menu-item\">
          <span></span>
          <div class=\"menu-item-text\">Logs</div>
        </li>
        <li class=\"menu-item\">
          <span></span>
          <div class=\"menu-item-text\">Users</div>
        </li>
        <li class=\"menu-item\">
          <span></span>
          <div class=\"menu-item-text\">Packet handler</div>
        </li>
        <li class=\"menu-item\">
          <span></span>
          <div class=\"menu-item-text\">Schedule tasks</div>
        </li>
        <li class=\"menu-item\">
          <span></span>
          <div class=\"menu-item-text\">Music</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class=\"content\">
      <div class=\"title\">Log in</title>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>"
```

Comment: What does your server's error log tell you about the error? How does this bash script look like? What did you try to resolve the problem?

Comment: What's the point in using a program to generate a static HTML document?

Comment: @user1934428 I'll need to add information from system variables or commands in the future

Comment: Why not use something like PHP, or any other programming language, that works way easier than your current concept?

Comment: @NicoHaase It's for university and it's required to only use bash scripts to provide the functionalities or HTML :/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an error in your HTML code, fix the following line in your code

```
<div class="title">Log in</title>
```

Comment: Please share more details such that others can learn from your answer. Does this really resolve the error message thrown on loading the CSS file? If yes, how does this work?

Comment: I thought it would have been obvious. You can not close a html DIV tag with a TITLE tag. In html if you open a DIV tag you must close it with a DIV tag.